# Get a phrase between "." and that has a specific word

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-core

Let's say I have the following text:

> "When I was growing up, we lived in a little house with a full basement." Mom made the basement cozy with a rug covering the concrete floor and a couch and chair that we could play on. , and that was where we kept most of our toys and the things we treasured.
>
> We went up and down those wooden stairs many times, and after a while they began to look pretty scuffed and scruffy. Mom decided she was going to paint them. That was in the days before quick-drying paints came into use, and it would take a full day for the paint to dry. "

I need a Regex with start and end delimited by "." and that contains two specific words (example -> the basement), the result would be:

> "Mom made the basement cozy with a rug covering the concrete floor and a couch and chair that we could play on."

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you have attempted for this? Also you need to provide us with an actual question.

Comment: a little editing goes a long way to making a question like this easy to answer.  A giant paragraph of undifferentiated text is too hard to skim .

Comment: So many questions.  Do you want to be able to handle proper nouns in the middle of your sentence?  What about quotation marks?  What about sentences that end in exclamation marks or question marks?  What if the sentence is the first sentence and is not preceded by a full stop?  What if the full stop at the end is omitted?  What if there are multiple matches?  What if the spacing between "the" and "basement" is inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
[A-Z][^.]*the basement[^.]*\.
```

**Explanation:**

`[A-Z]` - This regex starts matching with a capital letter as a sentence starts with a capital letter.

`[^.]*` - Then it can be followed by zero or more any characters other than literal dot

`the basement` - Followed by text as you want it to be in the middle of it.

`[^.]*` - Then further it can be followed by zero or more any characters other than literal dot

`\.` - Finally ending with a literal dot

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5UftYY/1)**

Comment: Capital letter for start of sentence?  That's probably not going to work in general.  What if you get a proper noun in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: English is hard though.  `Let's meet at 8:00 a.m. in the basement.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat robust solution. It handles periods (i.e. full stops) but not "dots" (e.g. "8:00 a.m." or "e.g.").

```
void Main()
{
    var s = 

    @"When I was growing up, we lived in a little house with a full basement. Mom made the basement cozy with a rug covering the concrete floor and a couch and chair that we could play on. , and that was where we kept most of our toys and the things we treasured.

    We went up and down those wooden stairs many times, and after a while they began to look pretty scuffed and scruffy. Mom decided she was going to paint them. That was in the days before quick-drying paints came into use, and it would take a full day for the paint to dry.";

    Console.WriteLine(Foo(s, "the", "basement"));

}

IEnumerable<string> Foo(string s, params string[] words)
{
    var regexes = from w in words select new Regex(w, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var xs = new Stack<List<char>>();
    xs.Push(new List<char>());

    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        xs.Peek().Add(c);

        if(c == '.')
            xs.Push(new List<char>());
    }               

    var candidates = xs.Reverse().Select (x => new string(x.ToArray()) );

    foreach (var candidate in candidates)
        if(regexes.All(x => x.IsMatch(candidate)))
            yield return candidate;
}
```